# Difference between `rails test <filename>` and `rails test`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What could be the difference between running the following two commands?

- `rails test test/controllers/api/<filename>`
- `rails test`

How do I know if there is a difference? The former works, and the latter does not; It seems not all fixtures are loaded.

**UPDATE**

```
$ rails test:all
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'test:all' (see --tasks)

$ rails --tasks
rails about                              # List versions of all Rails frame...
rails active_storage:install             # Copy over the migration needed t...
rails active_storage:install:migrations  # Copy migrations from active_stor...
rails app:template                       # Applies the template supplied by...
rails app:update                         # Update configs and some other in...
rails assets:clean[keep]                 # Remove old compiled assets
rails assets:clobber                     # Remove compiled assets
rails assets:environment                 # Load asset compile environment
rails assets:precompile                  # Compile all the assets named in ...
rails cache_digests:dependencies         # Lookup first-level dependencies ...
rails cache_digests:nested_dependencies  # Lookup nested dependencies for T...
rails clean                              # Remove any temporary products
rails clobber                            # Remove any generated files
rails db:create                          # Creates the database from DATABA...
rails db:drop                            # Drops the database from DATABASE...
rails db:environment:set                 # Set the environment value for th...
rails db:fixtures:load                   # Loads fixtures into the current ...
rails db:migrate                         # Migrate the database (options: V...
rails db:migrate:status                  # Display status of migrations
rails db:rollback                        # Rolls the schema back to the pre...
rails db:schema:cache:clear              # Clears a db/schema_cache.yml file
rails db:schema:cache:dump               # Creates a db/schema_cache.yml file
rails db:schema:dump                     # Creates a db/schema.rb file that...
rails db:schema:load                     # Loads a schema.rb file into the ...
rails db:seed                            # Loads the seed data from db/seed...
rails db:setup                           # Creates the database, loads the ...
rails db:structure:dump                  # Dumps the database structure to ...
rails db:structure:load                  # Recreates the databases from the...
rails db:version                         # Retrieves the current schema ver...
rails dev:cache                          # Toggle development mode caching ...
rails initializers                       # Print out all defined initialize...
rails log:clear                          # Truncates all/specified *.log fi...
rails middleware                         # Prints out your Rack middleware ...
rails notes                              # Enumerate all annotations (use n...
rails notes:custom                       # Enumerate a custom annotation, s...
rails restart                            # Restart app by touching tmp/rest...
rails routes                             # Print out all defined routes in ...
rails secret                             # Generate a cryptographically sec...
rails simplecov                          # Run tests
rails stats                              # Report code statistics (KLOCs, e...
rails test                               # Runs all tests in test folder ex...
rails test:db                            # Run tests quickly, but also rese...
rails test:system                        # Run system tests only
rails time:zones[country_or_offset]      # List all time zones, list by two...
rails tmp:clear                          # Clear cache, socket and screensh...
rails tmp:create                         # Creates tmp directories for cach...
rails yarn:install                       # Install all JavaScript dependenc...
```

This is for Rails 5. To clarify the tests are in `tests/controllers/` and `tests/controllers/api`. The test that runs when being specified but fails `rails test` is in the api subdirectory which I thought was getting loaded normally. I can see that the tests are being run, but the fixtures are not loaded correctly. However, I have moved the files to `tests/` for troubleshooting and the problem was not resolved, so I thought this was not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I could see that there is no such rake task `rails test:all` in your project and that is why it is failing to build the task.

`rails test` is the command to run all the tests at once and `rails test filepath` is used to test only the specified file.. similarly to run system tests use `rails test:system`

Comment: I wasn't under the assumption I should need to create anything for test:all, it should be a default rails function. I'm guessing there is a version mismatch between my version and the version used by the other person who suggested this command in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

`rails test` is used for testing all of the tests that are inside `test/` folder.

`rails test <file_path>` is used for testing in different location rather than `test/*.*` files. So, this is especially used when your test files are not in `test/`.

---

You may use `rails test:all` to test all the sub-directory files of the `test/` folder.

Comment: you may also try `rails test test/`